# Send mail from outlook account using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a WebApplication which is used by my Team Members. They are accessing WebApp with a tunnel link on their PC. There is a function where Team Mates send email by clicking on button. This function is working on fine for me, but when they try using this function Outlook triggers email from my Outlook which is on my PC instead of their individual Outlook account.

Here is the code to trigger email

```
using (Db db = new Db())
{
Ticket newDTO = db.Tickets.Find(id);

Application app = new Application();
MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Subject = "Feedback: Ticket Escalated " + newDTO.CaseId + " For Customer " + newDTO.EscalatedOn;
mailItem.To = newDTO.Email;
mailItem.CC = "lead@mydomain.com";
mailItem.HTMLBody = "Hello " + newDTO.Number + "<b>Feedback:</b>" + "<br /><br />" + newDTO.HowCanWeDeEscalate;
mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
mailItem.Display(false);
mailItem.Send();
}

How can I make this code work? So the email is sent by their individual outlook email and not mine.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (You need to configure the SMTP according to your server):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SO.DtProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("fromemail@mydomain.com");
            mail.To.Add("toemail@mydomain.com");
            mail.CC.Add("ccemail@mydomain.com");
            mail.Subject = "test some subject";
            mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = "some body text here";


            //SMTP Conbfiguration
            string clientServer = "mail.mydomain.netORwhatever";
            string smtpUserName = "fromemail@mydomain.com";
            string smtpPassword = "somepassword";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(clientServer);
            client.Port = 25; // 587;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true; //false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUserName, smtpPassword);
            client.EnableSsl = true; //false;

            try
            {
                await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle it
            }
            finally
            {
                mail.Dispose();
                client.Dispose();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. I am getting squiggly lines, see the error here please https://prnt.sc/11ms9qp

Comment: @RS try using  ```MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();``` rather than ```MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);``` which is ```using System.Net.Mail;```

Comment: Something like this ```MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("thesenderemail@mydomain.com");
            mail.To.Add(newDTO.Email);
            mail.CC.Add("lead@mydomain.com");
            mail.Subject = m.Konu;
            mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = m.Metin;```

Comment: How to Send from Outlook? MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(); 
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("lead@mydomain.com"); 
                    mail.To.Add(newDTO.Email); mail.CC.Add("lead@mydomain.com"); 
                    mail.Subject = "Test Subject"; 
                    mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true; 
                    mail.Body = "This is Body";
                    mailItem.Send(); Check This please

Comment: No Success with this code Application app = new Application();MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
var emailSend = "lead@test.com";mail.From = new MailAddress(emailSend) ;
mailItem.Subject = "Feedback: Ticket Escalated " + newDTO.CaseId + " For Customer " + newDTO.EscalatedOn;mailItem.To = newDTO.Email;mailItem.CC = "test@me.com";mailItem.HTMLBody = "Hello " + newDTO.Number + "<b>Feedback:</b>" + "<br /><br />" + newDTO.HowCanWeDeEscalate;mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;mailItem.Display(false);mailItem.Send();

Comment: I am fairly new , so just guide me here. You created a Class object, how do I use this in Controller Action Method. Kindly suggest. Thank you